# Given an array in which arr[i] = i-1 with the following method, what will be the output?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, methods

I'm given the following method written in pseudo-code

```
for i=1 to floor(n/2)
    if arr[i] != 0 then
       for(j=2 to floor(n/i)
         arr[i*j] = 0
```

**I need to find the output and to prove that it's indeed the output.**

So far I tried to write the code in Java and to try different inputs and array sizes but to no avail.
Putting it here if it's of any help:

```
public class Checking
{
    private static int method(int[] A,int n)
    {
        for (int i=1;i<=java.lang.Math.floor(n/2);i++)
        {
            if(A[i] != 0)
            {
                for(int j=2;j<=java.lang.Math.floor(n/i);j++)
                {
                    A[i*j]=0;
                    System.out.println("The index ofA["+i*j+"] became "+A[i*j]);
                }
            }

            //System.out.print(", "+A[i]);
        }

        for (int i=1;i<=java.lang.Math.floor(n/2);i++)
        {
            System.out.print(", "+A[i]);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] A = {-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23};
        System.out.println(method(A,20));
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's your question? Does your code give an error? In that case, include the error message. Does it give a wrong output? In that case, include expected and actual outputs and how they differ.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the following:

In your main method remove

```
System.out.println(method(A,20));
```

as it will always print 0 as you return 0; from the method().

As you print everything in your  method()  change the following (as it does not print the full array but from index 1 (missing index 0) to floor n/2)

```
for (int i=1;i<=java.lang.Math.floor(n/2);i++)
        {
            System.out.print(", "+A[i]);
        }
```

to

```
for (int i=0;i<A.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(", "+A[i]);
        }
```

So you can print the whole array.

For simplicity you can use Array's print method to print the array without a for loop

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but missing the first index is intentional, as the pseudo-code dictates (was weird for me too).
The rest is fixed but still my question remains unsolved :(

Comment: The pseudo-code explains how to update the array. The second loop (starting from index 0) shows how to print the array. So you use the pseudo code to update A but you need some code to print All the array date. I updated the answer with a simplest print solution for arrays